# Updating GCC from 4.2.1 in XCode 9.4.1 while keeping the rest to be the same

Tags: mac, libreoffice, xcode, c++, gcc

I am trying to build LibreOffice, which indicated on its guide that I must use XCode 9.4.1 as follows:

> NOTE: If you try to build LibreOffice on macOS Mojave 10.14, please use Xcode 9.4.1, otherwise, LibreOffice will become really unstable due to a problem with Xcode 10 ( tdf#121778 ).

But one of the error I encountered in the setup process:

```bsh
...
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -- works
...
-- Checking if compiler supports C++ unique_ptr
-- Checking if compiler supports C++ unique_ptr - no
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:79 (message):
  The C++ compiler does not support C++11 (e.g.  std::unique_ptr).


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/xxxx/Documents/workspace/lode/packages/cmake-3.10.0-rc3/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/xxxx/Documents/workspace/lode/packages/cmake-3.10.0-rc3/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
...
```

As stated in the error, it is really because the gcc does not support C++11 by default when I try to run it directly. But setting the switch `-std=c++11` works. But the problem is that I can't put the switch flag because I needed it to be the default.

I look for the way of how to change the default. I discovered later the gcc in the XCode bin is version 4.2.1, which by quoting

> No version of gcc fully conforms to any ANSI or ISO C standard by default. The default is always equivalent to -std=gnuNN, supporting the given standard with GNU-specific extensions. Prior to version 5 (and going back a number of years), the default was -std=gnu90. Starting with version 5, the default is -std=gnu11.

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458340/how-to-find-out-which-ansi-c-standard-my-gcc-works-with-by-default is probably the cause of why the gcc uses c++98 instead of c++11 by default (used in all the `.sh` scripts).

I am not sure how to update the gcc, seems like I can't just copy and paste the gcc binaries from other new XCode installation because it might have dependencies with other binaries. Is there any way of how I can solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: a) why are you trying to build something freely-available pre-compiled & b) why are you trying to use a completely outdated Xcode to do it?

Comment: a) i just want to try to contribute & it requires building, b) because they stated the need [https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingOnMac#Quick_Setup](here)

Comment: OK - that looks like it was written a year ago. I wish you luck but I think you're out on the bleeding edge.